# Auto bind Signalr "on" methods using interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

In my signalr app, I have a c# client interface:

```
public interface IFooClient
{
    Task OnFoo(string data);
}
```

with a hub like this:

```
public class FooHub : Hub<IFooClient>
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await this.Clients.Caller.OnFoo("data");
    }
}
```

In my angular app I bind the hub methods like this:

```
connection.on("onFoo", this.onFoo.bind(this)); //this.onFoo is a method on this Component
```

This works as expected. However I would like to take it a step further. I actually generate Typescript interfaces from the C# ones, which allows me to write the ng component like this:

```
export interface FooClient {  // auto generated
    onFoo(data: string): void;
}    

export class FooComponent implements FooClient {
  onFoo(data: string) {
    // ...
  }
```

This way, anytime the C# interface changes, the typescript one gets regenerated and the ng compiler will fail, forcing me to implement the missing method. What it doesn't force me to do, is to bind the method using signalr `on(...)`, that still needs to be done manually.

Is there any way to automatically bind the methods? I know the interface, I know the class implementing the interface, and I want to automatically connect the dots